# Is there a consistent way to send data to an Android activity, opening the activity if it is not already open?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I want to open an activity and send it some data. The activity could be in any state in it's lifecycle. I am frustrated because each method I am familiar with only works when the activity is in specific states.

If the activity is currently closed, then I could start it and send the data as extras with the intent. But this doesn't seem to work if activity is already open because you can't access to the most recent intent. If the activity is already open, then I can use the localbroadcast system. But local broadcasts don't work if the activity is closed to begin with.

Doubtless I am missing something. Does anyone know a consistent way to send data to an activity, opening it if it's not already open?

Comment: Is this a singleInstance Activity?

Comment: If by "local broadcasts", you're referring to `LocalBroadcastManager`, its `sendBroadcast()` method returns a `boolean` which indicates whether there's a Receiver currently registered for the given broadcast. If you use a unique broadcast for your `Activity`, register and unregister its Receiver appropriately, and `sendBroadcast()` returns `false`, you can then `startActivity()`. I'd imagine other event bus implementations have a similar mechanism.

Comment: @TheWanderer It isn't, but maybe it should be. I'm using this activity to ask for several permissions, then navigating back to the activity when the permissions are granted.

Comment: @MikeM. Yes, this complication is the sort of thing I was hoping to avoid. I can do it, but was hoping that there is a clean way. Surely I'm not the first who has tried to do something like this, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm not sure why you consider that a complication. It's simply `if (!LocalBroadcastManager...sendBroadcast(...)) { startActivity(...); }`..

Comment: @MikeM. Then you have to handle it two different ways on the receiving end too. Works, but in my opinion it has bad code smell.

Answer (score 4):

> But this doesn't seem to work if activity is already open because you can't access to the most recent intent

If this is a new instance of an activity that is already open, then you use `getIntent()`.

If, instead, you used flags or manifest entries to arrange to bring an existing instance of this activity back to the foreground, override `onNewIntent()`, and you get the most recent `Intent` that way.

> I want to open an activity from a service

Starting an activity from the background is the sort of thing that can really irritate users, as you do not know what the user is doing in the foreground. In most common scenarios, you are better served using a `Notification`.

Comment: Let me see if I understand you: I could make a new function called, say, handleIntent(Intent intent). Then I call it from both onNewIntent() and onCreate(), passing the most recent intents as you described getting them. Would this cover all cases and give me the most recent intent in all circumstances?

Comment: Regarding opening the activity from a service: I edited my question and took that part out because it is orthogonal to the real issue. This is actually an activity to ask the user for multiple permissions, and I want to redirect to the activity with a confirmation once each permission is granted. One of the permissions comes from a service, another from a BroadcastReceiver, and another from a background thread. I just want a way to open the activity and pass it some data that works from anywhere.

Comment: @Tyler: "Would this cover all cases and give me the most recent intent in all circumstances?" -- it should.

Answer (score 0):

[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to the rescue
[image: Event Bus flow]

**EventBus in 3 steps**

> Define events:

```
public static class MessageEvent { /* Additional fields if needed */ }
```

> Prepare subscribers: Declare and annotate your subscribing method,
>   optionally specify a thread mode:

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = ThreadMode.MAIN)  
public void onMessageEvent(MessageEvent event) {/* Do something */};
```

Register and unregister your subscriber. For example on Android, activities and fragments should usually register according to their life cycle:

```
 @Override
 public void onStart() {
     super.onStart();
     EventBus.getDefault().register(this);
 }



@Override
 public void onStop() {
     super.onStop();
     EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this);
 }
```

> Post events:

```
EventBus.getDefault().post(new MessageEvent());
```

Read the full [getting started guide.](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/)

Comment: This is good to know about. But unless I'm mistaken, this will only work if the activity is already alive, correct?

Comment: You mentioned in your question that you were able to start the activity if it wasn’t active, so I just showed you the path.